# Algorithm of Here Maps use to route between 2 points?

Tags: android, here-api

I wonder which algorithm Here maps use to compute the route between 2 points ? Has HERE ever mentioned about it ?

Comment: Best if you show the work and not merely ask opinions. It is best you search via google to if you need to learn about distance calculation algorithms.

Comment: Google map is use dijkstra algorithm. but I didn't found algorithms of Here Map

Answer (score 0):

If we wanted to calculate the distance, we would typically make use of the `Haversine Algorithm`, because remember, **the earth is not flat**. To make our lives easier, the `HERE SDK` takes care of this algorithm for us.
Hope you got the idea.

According to **wiki** : The `haversine formula` determines the great-circle distance between two points on a sphere given their longitudes and latitudes. The term haversine was coined in 1835 by James Inman. These names follow from the fact that they are customarily written in terms of the haversine function, given by hav(θ) = sin2(θ2).

Comment: Actually, I want know Algorithm name Here SDK use to calculate route. but I did'nt found it in google search. I guess Here protected their technology.

Comment: No its not true, You can search about haversine function

Comment: Google map is use dijkstra algorithm to find route. but I didn't found algorithms of Here Map. I mean calculate a route. Calculate the distance(haversine) isn't that I want to

Comment: HERE uses a custom algorithm that takes in much more data than only Dijkstra. Details about the algorithm are not publicly available.